# Does Amber's bidding process have known issues, and if so, how can they be fixed?

Tags: character-creation, amber-diceless

I recently acquired at some considerable cost a copy of *Amber Diceless Role-Playing*, which I had long wondered about. Knowing of some potential players of the game at my local game store, I posted on their website asking about interest in getting a game together.

No sooner had I done this than I was bombarded with demands that I announce how I would deal with the problems with the stat auction process — which quickly became mildly acrimonious, causing me to withdraw the suggestion altogether.

What are the known issues with the bidding process, and what fixes are there for them?

I've combed the web but the majority of the search engine hits are dead links now, and the sites I do find are moribund.

Comment: I think this title is in grave danger of being "too subjective and argumentative", even though the question that follows is reasonable. How about "Does the Amber Diceless System bidding process have known issues, and if so, how can they be fixed?"

Comment: I also think it might be better to give an example of the issues you've encountered - it's pretty vague right now.

Comment: Yeah, if I were a normal guy and not a mod I'd vote to close on this due to vagueness and argumentativity.

Comment: I read the guide for posting very, very carefully before I asked. The moderator may remove it if it really is that offensive (though the actual answers given would suggest people here are a little more balanced and adult than they are being given credit for). The question was serious and the phrasing carefully chosen. Those who are in a position to know what is wrong with ADRPG will not be confused by the perceived lack of examples in my post. Argumentative people with no useful knowledge will not have a basis on which to begin a flamewar. I thought this was the ideal.

Comment: The problem with the question is not it's content, but the title.  The question should be "How do you deal with the issues surrounding the points bidding process?", asking about whether Amber is "broken" is a one-way ticket to closeville.

Comment: If the title was "Problems with Amber Diceless Attribute Auctions" and you were more straightforward with the info in the question, this would probably reopen and be useful.  The title's turning people off and you're being needlessly cagey about what you're asking - this isn't a normal forum, "vagueness" is a reason to close here.

Comment: Title fixed, and Amber experts probably know about the *well known* issues enough to answer this usefully, so voting to reopen. (Besides, it was closed with our bad-old close reasons. Today it would at best be held as "unclear", but yeah, it's likely clear to Amber *experts*.)

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to determine from the information you give what "the" problem with the attribute auction is. There are certainly well known ways to try to game the system - they're even [noted in its Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_Diceless_Roleplaying_Game#The_Attribute_Auction) - but they are arguably part of the cutthroat competition aspect of the game.  Some folks have proposed [alternate schemes to the auction](http://amberway.free.fr/REBMA1.pdf) to mitigate these perceived problems.

Answer (score 3):

There are issues with the auction process that can be dealt with in multiple ways. One would be to skip the auction and have all the players design their characters within a points budget decided by the ref, then assign ratings based on actual points spent.

This is likely to end up with players who have no idea how they rate against the other players and this will affect play (you don't know how to scheme against the other players successfully, if you have no idea how their stats compare to yours). This isn't necessarily bad, but does affect play.

Another possible solution is to have a two-round auction, with the ability to give a second bid, after the initial ranking has been read out.

Then, of course, you can just run with it as written, it does have some charm and if one (or more) players are dead set at being 1st in one attribute or another, they can easily end up with fewer points left than they initially intended.

Comment: Is there an accepted "right" way in the player community? A consensus?

Comment: Not that I've seen, as long as you get a consensus in a player group, you've done well.